# Grails - How to implement a foreign key relationship not using an id column?

Tags: grails

Have been trying to look for an answer for hours, but have so far not managed to come up with an adequate solution, so I'm hoping someone here might have some more experience with Grails, and implementing custom relationships in it.

My problem is that I have two classes:

Company
OrderConfig

OrderConfig contains two references to Company. 1 for a consignee, 1 for a shipper. I implemented the relationship (see below), and everything looks dandy, with my order_config table containing both a consignee_company_id column and a shipper_company_id column.

However, I do not want or need a company_id column at all. I would prefer using the CompanyName as the identifying column. How can I prevent Grails from automatically adding the id column to the company table, and instead use the companyName column as the primary key, thus ensuring my order_config table will be generated containing the companyName and not the company_id?

I tried embedding the company in the orderconfig class, and wrestled with all kinds of other options including the mappings, however I ran into trouble with each and every one of them.

Thanks in advance!

My code so far:

```
class OrderConfig {
 static hasMany = [consignee:Company, shipper:Company]

  String toString() {
    return "${consignee}"
 }

    static constraints = {
      consignee (blank:false, maxSize:10)
      shipper (blank:false, maxSize:10)
  }

  Company consignee
  Company shipper
}




class Company {
    String toString() {
    return "${companyName}"
 }

static constraints = {
    companyName(blank:false, maxSize:10)
    companyAddress1(blank:false, maxSize:40)
    companyAddress2(blank:false, maxSize:40)
    companyAddress3(blank:false, maxSize:40)
    companyAddress4(blank:false, maxSize:40)
    companyZipCode(blank:false, maxSize:36)
    companyCountry(blank:false, maxSize:36)
}

  String companyName
  String companyAddress1
  String companyAddress2
  String companyAddress3
  String companyAddress4
  String companyZipCode
  String companyCountry
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the advanced GORM config options in the documentation, in section 5.5.2.1

There is an example

```
class Person {
  String firstName
  static hasMany = [addresses:Address]
  static mapping = {
      table 'people'
      firstName column:'First_Name'
      addresses joinTable:[name:'Person_Addresses', key:'Person_Id', column:'Address_Id']
  }
}
```

there you can see how they are specifying the key and column name on which to do the stuff.

Edit -- I reread your question: if you are asking how to change it so Company has an assigned id, you might be able to do something like this example

```
static mapping = {
    id generator:'assigned', column:'column_name',name:'propertyName'
}
```

where more options are available here: http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.x/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html

Comment: Hi, and thanks for that. That solved part of the problem, in that the generated Order table now contains a reference to a varchar column, and the Company table having the Company_Name column as the primary key.  However, the relationship column in Order is still labelled consignee_id and shipper_id. When I try and compile, it works, but when trying to add a new order, the app throws an error: Cannot invoke method isInstance() on null object. Any idea how to work around this? I have been trying various solutions, but none worked so far.