# Grails GORM mapping FK that is not the PK of the other table

Tags: database, grails, groovy, relational-database, grails-orm

How do I map a GORM association where the foreign key is not a PK of the other table?

I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `supplier` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `partner_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `supplier_id` int(11) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `ad` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `partner_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `supplier_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ad_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ad_details` text NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

The FK relationship is between `ad.supplier_id` and `supplier.supplier_id` (**NOT** `supplier.id`).

---

EDIT: The answer by @tim_yates below seems to be partially working.

Since `supplier.supplier_id` is not the PK of the `supplier` table, therefore it is possible for `supplier.supplier_id` to be duplicated.

In fact, the key of the `supplier` table is the tuple (`supplier.supplier_id`, `supplier.partner_id`). How do I model this constraint?

Answer (score 1):

[This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4617047/6509) seems to show you should be able to add (using [advanced Gorm Mapping](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.x/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.5.2.1%20Table%20and%20Column%20Names)):

```
  class Ad {
    Partner partner
    Supplier supplier
    String details

    static mapping = {
      supplier column:'supplier_id'
      details type:"text"
    }
  }
```

Though I've not tested this...